# How can I change google_ads schema in dbt project?

Tags: google-ads-api, dbt

I have a dbt project and I'm using ad_reporting model.
all the sources are working good, except than google_ads.
and that's because I don't have google_ads schema, instead I have google_ads_us schema.
I tried to change it in main dbt_project.yml file:

```
vars:
    google_ads_schema: google_ads_us
```

but still when I'm running this command:

```
dbt run --select ad_reporting
```

I keep get this error:

```
Database Error in model stg_google_ads (models\stg_google_ads.sql)
SQL compilation error:
Object 'DATABASE.HISTORY_GOOGLE_ADS.GOOGLE_ADS__URL_AD_ADAPTER' does not exist or not 
authorized.
compiled SQL at target\run\ad_reporting\models\stg_google_ads.sql
```

the HISTORY_ prefix is from profiles.yml file (SCHEMA).

Anyone know where else I need to change the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the package to find the specified `vars` it has defined, you will need to do four things, all specified in the [docs](https://github.com/fivetran/dbt_google_ads):

**1. Make sure that `ad_reporting` for google_ads is enabled** -->

```yaml
# inside your dbt_project.yml

vars:
  ad_reporting__google_ads_enabled: true
```

**2. Also, make sure that you let dbt know where to look for the google_ads raw data**:

```yaml
# inside your dbt_project.yml

vars:
  google_ads_database: your_database_name  # in our case, `raw`
  google_ads_schema: your_schema_name      # in our case, `google_ads`
```

**3. Define the schemas where dbt will build the models for both `google_ads` and `google_ads_source`** -->

```yaml
# inside your dbt_project.yml

models:
  google_ads:
    +schema: my_new_schema_name # leave blank for just the target_schema
  google_ads_source:
    +schema: my_new_schema_name # leave blank for just the target_schema
```

Since, as according to the docs:

"*By default this package will build the Google Ads staging models within a schema titled (<target_schema> + _stg_google_ads) and the Google Ads final models with a schema titled (<target_schema> + _google_ads) in your target database.*"

**4. Specify which API you're going to use (Google Adwords or Google Ads)**:

```yaml
# inside your dbt_project.yml

vars:
    api_source: google_ads  # adwords by default and is case sensitive!
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did that, and now I get another error: dbt found two resources with the name "google_ads__url_ad_adapter". Since these resources have the same name,
  dbt will be unable to find the correct resource when ref("google_ads__url_ad_adapter") is used. To fix this,
  change the name of one of these resources:
  - model.google_ads.google_ads__url_ad_adapter (models\url_google_ads\google_ads__url_ad_adapter.sql)
  - model.google_ads.google_ads__url_ad_adapter (models\url_adwords\google_ads__url_ad_adapter.sql)
but adwords is the default choice. how can I change it?

Comment: Forgot to add that you also need to specify the API you're going to use (Google Adwords or Google Ads). Updated the answer accordingly :)